# What is a good session store for a single-host Node.js production app?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node's Express w/ Connect middleware.  Connect's memory session store isn't fit for production:

> ```
> Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and obviously only work within a single process.
> ```

For larger deployments, mongo or redis makes sense.

But what is a good solution for a single-host app in production?

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Spent the day looking into this. Here are the options I've discovered. Requests/second are performed via `ab -n 100000 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:9778/` on my local machine.

- no sessions - fast (438 req/sec)
- [cookieSession](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html): requires no external service, minor speed impact (311 req/sec) - fastest, sessions will expire with the cookie (customised by `maxAge`)
- [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis): requires redis server, large speed impact (4 req/sec with redis2go and redisgreen) - faster than mongo, sessions will be deleted after a while (customised by `ttl`)
- [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) - requires mongodb server, large speed impact (2 req/sec with mongohq) - slower than redis, requires manual `clear_interval` to be set to cleanup sessions

Here is the coffeescript I used for cookieSession:

```
server.use express.cookieSession({
    secret: appConfig.site.salt
    cookie: maxAge: 1000*60*60
})
```

Here is the coffeescript I use for redis:

```
RedisSessionStore ?= require('connect-redis')(express)
redisSessionStore ?= new RedisSessionStore(
    host: appConfig.databaseRedis.host
    port: appConfig.databaseRedis.port
    db: appConfig.databaseRedis.username
    pass: appConfig.databaseRedis.password
    no_ready_check: true
    ttl: 60*60  # hour
)
server.use express.session({
    secret: appConfig.site.salt
    cookie: maxAge: 1000*60*60
    store: redisSessionStore
})
```

Here is my coffeescript for mongo:

```
server.use express.session({
    secret: appConfig.site.salt
    cookie:
        maxAge: 100*60*60
    store: new MongoSessionStore({
        db: appConfig.database.name
        host: appConfig.database.host
        port: appConfig.database.port
        username: appConfig.database.username
        password: appConfig.database.password
        auto_reconnect: appConfig.database.serverOptions.auto_reconnect
        clear_interval: 60*60  # hour
    })
})
```

Now of course, the remote redis and mongo databases will be slower than their local equivalents. *I just couldn't get the local equivalents working, especially considering the installation and maintenance time for me was far more than what I was willing to invest when compared with hosted remote alternatives, something I feel is true for others too hence why these hosted remote database services exist in the first place!*

For local database benhmarks, see [@Mustafa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797898/130638).

Happy for someone to [edit this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13049549/edit) to add their local database benchmarks to the mix.

Comment: Wow, nice seeing numbers. Certainly affected my decisions. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, it would be really great to see MemoryStore benchmarked with these - any chance? ;)

Comment: Actually, you should use redis in your localhost to benchmark, using redis remotely is obviously slow

Comment: Happy for someone to edit the answer with local redis and mongo benchmarks, I just couldn't get them going locally as the installation and maintenance time was more than I wanted to invest when compared with hosted or cookie alternatives.

Comment: FALSE: no way to remove old records with no maxage in mongodb, see here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: @mattdlockyer that comment was related to the adapter that lacked support for it, hence the link. I've removed that comment as the adapter has now been fixed - https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/issues/46

Comment: Of course it will be slower, you are using external servers! This answer is largely wrong! You are comparing apples with oranges..

Comment: @Mustafa see my comment a few comments back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app/13049549?noredirect=1#comment23040609_13049549

Comment: I've updated the answer to make my stance on the local vs remote issue more visible. As well as add a link to your answer :)

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Comment: As per my understanding cookie-session will be stored in users browser. Does this pose a security risk of compromising some secure data that I need to store in session.?

Answer (score 79):

Since the accepted answer is only connecting to remote hosts, it is obvious that it will be always slower than localhost. Even if it is the next computer in your home, it would take milliseconds to read from that computer, but local memory takes only nanoseconds. You should compare them by using locally installed servers.

Here are my results from my local pc: You see, redis is almost as fast as in-memory in under high load. You can clone my the repo that these test codes are available: https://github.com/mustafaakin/express-session-store-benchmark

```
Concurrency: 1
none       4484.86 [#/sec] 
memory     2144.15 [#/sec] 
redis      1891.96 [#/sec] 
mongo      710.85 [#/sec] 
Concurrency: 10
none       5737.21 [#/sec] 
memory     3336.45 [#/sec] 
redis      3164.84 [#/sec] 
mongo      1783.65 [#/sec] 
Concurrency: 100
none       5500.41 [#/sec] 
memory     3274.33 [#/sec] 
redis      3269.49 [#/sec] 
mongo      2416.72 [#/sec] 
Concurrency: 500
none       5008.14 [#/sec] 
memory     3137.93 [#/sec] 
redis      3122.37 [#/sec] 
mongo      2258.21 [#/sec]
```

The session used pages are very simple pages;

```
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    if ( req.session && req.session.no){
        req.session.no = req.session.no + 1;
    } else {
        req.session.no = 1;
    }
    res.send("No: " + req.session.no);
});
```

Redis store config:

```
app.use(express.session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 2,
        }),
    secret: 'hello'
}));
```

Mongo store config:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: 'mongodb://localhost/test-session'
    }),
    secret: 'hello'
}));
```

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Answer (score 9):

Another good option is memcached. The session states are lost if memcached is restarted, but there is virtually never any reason to do that. You can leave the cache running all the time even when you restart your app server. Access to the session data is virtually instantaneous and memcached will run happily with whatever (appropriate) amount of memory you give it. And I've never seen memcached crash (on Linux).

https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache

Things to keep in mind about memcached generally:

- Never have whitespace in your cache keys
- Be aware that there is a maximum cache key length, including any namespace prefix you might use. If your cache key is too long, use a 1-way hash of it instead.

Neither of these should be an issue with session storage; just with generalized caching.

Comment: Do you know how to plug that into connect middleware's session handler? (I'm a n00b in this area)

Comment: @Chocohound Did you found out..
i could able to connect to Memcache server.. but how do i configure the session store with memcache in environments file?

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Comment: As listed on https://github.com/expressjs/session, there is a Memcached session store (connect-memcached) available now:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-memcached

Answer (score 7):

I've gone with a MongoDB session store using [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo).

Install with `npm install connect-mongo` and replace the existing MemoryStore with

`app.use(express.session({ store: new MongoStore({ db: 'some-database' }) }));`

It manages the database side of sessions automatically.

Answer (score 5):

I would still use Redis even for local development. This is helpful because it stores the session even when you restart the Node application, keeping your browser session logged in. Redis by default saves the session in memory, same as connect's memory store is simple to configure (I just run it in screen along with my node apps) can support multiple applications if you just use a different database or session value in the configuration.

Comment: i would not use different stores for dev and prod, you will undoubtedly have uncaught errors doing it this way. Tim is correct, use redis for local and prod.

Comment: Not much fun if you develop on a windows box though.

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Answer (score 3):

I'm just exploring node.js myself, but if you don't need to store a lot of information in the session object -- you might want to explore secure cookies.

Secure cookies store session information as part of the cookie that the browser stores and forwards with each request. They are encrypted to prevent a user from forging a valid cookie.

The advantage is that you don't have to maintain state at the server -- this solution scales well and is simple to implement.

The disadvantage is that you can only store up to about 4KB and that data gets sent to the server on *every* request (But you can have multiple fictitious domains pointing at your server so you don't impose that baggage on publicly visible static content, for example).

Searching the web it seems like there are at least two implementations of secure cookies for node.js. Not sure how production ready they are, though:

https://github.com/benadida/node-client-sessions/blob/master/lib/client-sessions.js

https://github.com/caolan/cookie-sessions

Comment: Funny, Ben Adida is actually a friend of mine.  Small world!

Comment: I am not an expert, but I thought general consensus is that secure cookies aren'... well.. secure.  I'll do some reading but I don't want to do anything that's not mainstream yet.

Comment: Well, you could always go and implement a simple session store based on files - something similar to what PHP does. Assuming the OS caches the files you'll get reasonable performance I guess. Or you could use tmpfs which is memory-backed filesystem.

Comment: Seems cookie sessions is now part of the official connect distro via [the cookieSession middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html)

Comment: Another data point to consider. Ruby on Rails default session store is Cookie-based (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb).

Comment: This post might explain more:
http://wonko.com/post/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-cookies-to-store-session-data

Comment: cookie-parser middleware signs its cookies with the secret to prevent tampering. See https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature for the implementation.

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??

Comment: As per my understanding cookie-session will be stored in users browser. Does this pose a security risk of compromising some secure data that I need to store in session.?

Comment: @JohnsonCherian: express cookie session does not encrypt cookies -- only signs them (see https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session/issues/9) so you must be careful not to store secret data there. This is a security risk (or one that is waiting to happen when you eventually forget about it and do store sensitive data in the sesion).

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate that this is an old question, but I came across it while searching for a solution to a similar problem. I had already decided to use memcached for session storage on Linux (with [connect-memcached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-memcached)), but I also required the ability to run on Windows. I spent a while trying to find an in-memory session storage for a single-process node app. Redis and Memcached don't appear to be well-supported on Windows, and I didn't want the additional complexity of their installation.

I found [session-memory-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-memory-store) in another Stack Overflow thread, which looks good but significantly increased the size of my dependencies.

Finally, I found [memorystore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memorystore) *in the documentation for [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)*. I had missed it originally due to the similarly of its name to the default `MemoryStore`, but it's exactly what I was looking for:

> express-session full featured MemoryStore module without leaks!

I'm now using connect-memcached when running in a cluster (on Linux only), and memorystore when running a single process (on Linux or Windows).

I thought it worth posting this as another answer, just in case anyone else makes the mistake of missing memorystore as I initially did.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed

Answer (score 1):

Check out my benchmarks at https://github.com/llambda/express-session-benchmarks showing comparisons of different session implementations.

Comment: i was using cookie-sessiosn but there is sessiosn data stored somewhere or not because what was happening in my case was current sessions was getting shown only but not the previous ones ??