# How to fix the connection.session issue

Tags: node.js

I'm getting bellow warning when using `NODE_ENV=production`. What's the fix for this?

> Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
>       designed for a production environment, as it will leak
>       memory, and obviously only work within a single process.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production#10761522][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production#10761522

Answer (score 8):

It could be a good idea to use Redis as your session manager. It appears as though you're using either the Express or Connect framework, and for either of them you could use an npm package [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) (having installed Redis). With that installed the express code would look something like this:

```
var express = require ( 'express' )
   , RedisStore = require ( 'connect-redis' ) ( express )
   , sessionStore = new RedisStore ()
   , app = express.createServer ()
   ;

app.configure ( function () {

   app.use ( express.cookieParser () );
   app.use ( express.session ( {
    secret: "keyboard cat", store: sessionStore, key: 'hello.sid'
   } ) );
...
```

Comment: i was used Redis for session store. but here i need just for admin authentication. That's why i'm looking for simple solution

Comment: @GaneshKumar this [so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app) deals with specifically your problem. Perhaps instead of a database you may wish to explore the secure cookie route described in the question linked.