# Using MemoryStore in production

Tags: node.js

Today I ran my Node.js application in "production" mode for the first time and got this warning:

```
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and obviously only work within a single process.
```

I only need to run a single process, but what should I use instead? I want my sessions to reside in RAM for fast access. I also want to be able to discard all the sessions by simply shutting down the Node app.

It seems an overkill to install Redis, MongoDB or another database just for this simple task. I also don't understand why is MemoryStore included in Node when it should not really be used?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MemoryStore is just for (rapid) development mode, because if your app restarts (process dies) you will lose all the session data (that resided in the memory of that process).

If you don't want to use a database, use encrypted cookie storage instead.

http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html

Answer (score 82):

Ok, after talking to Connect developers, I got more information. There are two things considered memory leaks here:

1. problem with JSON parsing which is already fixed in recent versions
2. the fact that there is no cleanup of expired sessions if the users never access them (i.e. the only cleanup is on-access)

The solution seems to be rather simple, at least this is what I plan to do: use setInterval to periodically clean up the expired sessions. MemoryStore provides all() to get the list, and we can use get() to force reading and thus expire them. Pseudo-code:

```
function sessionCleanup() {
    sessionStore.all(function(err, sessions) {
        for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
            sessionStore.get(sessions[i], function() {} );
        }
    });
}
```

Now just call sessionCleanup periodically via setInterval() and you have automatic garbage collection for expired sessions. No more memory leaks.

Comment: I discovered that you could also use Redis and Mongo as a backing store and have the db clean it up. In the case of Mongo, you can set expiration date while ensuring indexing.

Comment: It's really a stupid thing they've done by putting this message there. It's like "we could've made it right but instead we'll just make it wrong and you go play a guessing game on the internets. ha ha! losers!"

Comment: what is the value of the var sessionStore ?

Comment: sessionStore? Is that a node.js global variable? If not, how can I get a reference to the session Store in node.js?

Comment: @MilanBabuskov - do you put this in your `app.js` file?  Is there an option to issue a callback inside express session?  A little more detail on how to impement this would be great.

Comment: @asdfasdfads I think there's some good there coming from their decision not to provide a fix. This forces every developer or team to explicitly choose a session store library rather than default to one, which increases security through obscurity in the case the default one is ever compromised. Session data is generally filled with really important data. I don't entirely agree with the decision, but I see its merits.

Comment: @windchime I believe he is refering to the MemoryStore exported by express session [https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js)
An instance of MemoryStore (called sessionStore) should probably be used in session's initialization, and can then be accessed elsewhere using export

Answer (score 49):

So the accepted answer to this is [edit: was] pretty much a hack, and the others are just recommending using a database which I think is overkill.

I had the same problem and just replaced express-session with [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session).

To do this simply install `cookie-session`:

```
npm install cookie-session
```

Then in your `app.js`, find where `express-session` is being used and replace with `cookie-session`.

```
app.use(require('cookie-session')({
    // Cookie config, take a look at the docs...
}));
```

You may need to change some other things, for me is was a simple swap-out-bobs-your-uncle-no-harm-done.

Comment: how did you do that.

Comment: This is actually an answer that is useful. Thanx.

Comment: the difference is that `cookie-session` stores the data on the client, whereas `express-session` stores data on the server.

Answer (score 12):

This module was designed to deal with the memory leak issue.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-memory-store

The accepted answer may be fine. However, since this question shows up high in the list of search results I figured I would include this in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Haven't tried this but it looks like a great fix for the situation (if OP is ok with lost sessions on app restart)

Comment: From your link: "It's highly not recommend to use it in production!". The question is about "Using MemoryStore in production".

Comment: Right, but only because "you can't share the session with others process or other service." Meaning, there are other more practical solutions out there. But this does solve the memory leak issue, so if those are not concerns for you then it's fine to use and addresses the concern in the question.

Answer (score 8):

I think the consensus around the web is that the right way would be to indeed use a DB for that, but if you're positive you don't want to do that, then suppress the warning -- the warning is not law.

However, since you and I both agree that the memory leak is a real problem, it is hard to justify saying redis is overkill, since it would solve your problem.

> I also don't understand why is MemoryStore included in Node when it
>   should not really be used

that is a great point -- but to that I would say that node iself has only recently itself become *production ready*.  Some people would not agree with the notion that it is at all.

Comment: Suppressing the warning won't make the memory leak go away.

Comment: lol this is why they advise against you using it in production. so the alternative is to use an alternate method of storage, isn't it?

Comment: I guess I just don't like the alternatives I found so far. I'm looking for a simple in-memory javascript alternative, not a database system. I really don't understand why don't they fix it. I mean, how hard can a simple Memory Store be... I'm just hoping someone has already done it, so I don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I feel your pain, but node is pretty bleeding edge right now.. it sortof comes with the territory

Comment: MemoryStore is not included in Node, it's included in Express/Connect

Comment: but *why* is there that "consensus"? Is it because it will work across processes (node cluster) ?

Answer (score 6):

The alternative is to use Redis or Mongo as a store. With Mongo you use the [express-session-mongo](https://github.com/davglass/express-session-mongo) module.

There is an advice to remove stale sessions with an indexing option:

```
var MongoStore = require('express-session-mongo');
app.use(express.session({ store: new MongoStore() }));

db.sessions.ensureIndex( { "lastAccess": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Since stale sessions are removed by the database itself, Express session doesn't need to handle the cleanup by itself.

**EDIT**: It seems like you need to have your own "lastAccess" field. When you access it you update that field yourself. Check the MongoDB documentation [expire-data](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

**EDIT2**:

Now becomes `db.sessions.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )`

The Mongo background thread to check this field runs every 60 seconds. So the timing to remove the document is not exact.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having trouble with Redis try the following - hope this helps.

I'm using Redis for DEV and PROD and targeting Express v4.
On Windows I'm using the lightweight MSOpenTech Redis v3.0 toolset, otherwise, I just use the Heroku Redis Addon. To get it to work via Node hasn't been too hard - so far...

```
var session = require('express-session');

. . .

var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var redisClient = require('redis').createClient(process.env.REDIS_URL);

var redisOptions = { 
        client: redisClient, 
        no_ready_check: true,
        ttl: 600,
        logErrors: true
};

var redisSessionStore = new RedisStore(redisOptions);

app.use(session({
    store: redisSessionStore,
    secret: 'Some.Long.Series.of.Crazy.Words.and.Jumbled.letter.etc',
    resave: true,       
    saveUninitialized: true 
}));
```

Good luck!

ps. I only just re-read the original query and noticed this - sorry!

> It seems an overkill to install Redis, MongoDB or another database just for this simple task.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
import createMemoryStore from "memorystore";
...
// Memory store
const MemoryStore = createMemoryStore(session);
app.use(session({
    ...
    store: new MemoryStore({
        checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
    }),
    ...
}))
```

Fix the problem in my case

Comment: and this is the exact sample usage from the MemoryStore package itself

Answer (score 0):

If you use OSX use

```
brew install memcached
```

if linux

```
apt install memcached
```

solve session message, becose de app can connect to 127.0.0.1:11211 memcache service.