# Node : Forever not start node app throws error of listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, forever

I am facing issue with `forever` in my `node app`.

when i start app using `forever start app.js` it throws following error in error log

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1043:14)
at listen (net.js:1065:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1139:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/AdminPanelCodeCMS/app.js:48:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:935:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #8
```

I try to change port and also restart server but still issue there.
I am beginner so not able to solve issue, so please help me.

**Node : I am using nginx on ubuntu server for multiple node app.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MemoryStore in production](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The `MemoryStore` message is just a warning and shouldn't prevent execution.

Comment: What error you are getting when you are using `node app.js` in Terminal? Which port you are using for you nodejs application?

Comment: I already posted error, and I use 5555 port.