# MemoryStore leaking memory in SailsJs App

Tags: sails.js

A few days ago, I run SailsJs app for the first time in production. This warning showed up.

```
Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
```

I understand that a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production) has been asked and the answer seems to be periodically cleaning up sessionStore with code like.

```
function sessionCleanup() {
   sessionStore.all(function(err, sessions) {
      for (var i = 0; i < sessions.length; i++) {
         sessionStore.get(sessions[i], function() {} );
      }
   });
}
```

How can I get reference to sessionStore in sails.js?

Comment: You better don't use MemoryStore at all. If you will store data in memory in production mode then you'll face many problems with scaling.

Comment: how can I disable it?

Comment: Just update your Sails config where you are set up session configuration.

Comment: My session configuration(config/session.js) only has a secret property. Nothing else. After reading Sails documentation and comments inside, I still could not find a way to disable sessionStore.

Comment: You must provide another adapter for your session storage also. Take a look at full example - http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/session-js

Comment: Is the only thing I need to do is to provide another adapter for my session storage? Do I need to change something else to disable the default session storage? I could not find anything in that example which turned off sessionStore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89518/discussion-between-eugene-obrezkov-and-windchime).

Comment: The change makes the warning disappear. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All what you need to do is just replace memory adapter in `config/session.js` with another adapter, Redis, for instance.

```
module.exports.session = {
  secret: '<YOUR_SECRET>',
  adapter: 'redis',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  ttl: <REDIS_TTL_IN_SECONDS>,
  pass: <REDIS_PASSWORD>
  prefix: 'sess:'
};
```