# Why does the nodejs app crash after deploying it on bluemix?

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, express, ibm-cloud

I am using express & passport modules for user authentication on `nodejs`. The code runs fine locally. But when uploaded to the bluemix server, it runs for two login instances or for some time-out and subsequently the server crashes. Here is the log from bluemix :

```
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-02-29T15:03:22.974+0530[App/0] ERRmemory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-02-29T15:03:22.974+0530[App/0] ERRdesigned for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-02-29T15:03:22.985+0530[App/0] OUTServer is running @ http://localhost:64134
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERRError: Quit inactivity timeout
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR at Quit.emit (events.js:166:7)
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERRevents.js:141
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR ^
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR at Quit. (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:160:17)
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
2016-02-29T15:04:23.173+0530[App/0] ERR at Quit._onTimeout
(/home/vcap/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:116:8) 2016-02-29T15:04:23.856+0530[API/9]OUTApp instance exited with guid caa03cfb-bf79-43e1-997d-4d76d50a41a7 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"caa03cfb-bf79-43e1-997d-4d76d50a41a7", "version"=>"0000dfe2-af05-4f9a-b244-3902edb3d5ff", "instance"=>"88586613847b4d098601a29ffad5d390", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1456738463}
```

Comment: This question might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production

Comment: Or this https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/1223. The problem there was resolved by upgrading from node v4.2.0 to v4.2.2.

Comment: If those don't help can you please indicate which buildpack you're using and which version of Node.js you're using?