# Best session storage in ExpressJS - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, redis

I'm building my first (and rather big) NodeJS application. I need excellent performance since it's a big all AJAX (AngularJS) interface with a lot of requests from a lot of users.

I'm building the login system, and I need to choose which storage engine I will use. I narrowed down my search to 4 choices :

- [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) : read a lot of nice things about it, but requires the installation of MongoDB
- [connect-redis](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis) : read a lot of nice things about it, but requires the installation of Redis
- [connect-pg](https://github.com/jebas/connect-pg) : don't know the performance but that's the DB we're using so no additional installation needed
- cookieSession : according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13049549/1287598) is very fast, but I'm a bit confused at to why it's so fast and everywhere I look people seem to ignore this option

Which setup should give me the best performance possible? Without of course impacting functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: redis can be added in one line from npm, not sure about the others...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right answer is clear by following your links and looking at the number of stars and forks. cookieSession is unacceptable because it doesn't work across multiple machines, which you will absolutely need. connect-mongo doesn't make any sense because it's not worth installing and maintaining mongo just for cookies.

connect-pg would probably be fine for you, but why risk slowing down your database when there is no need. Redis is an incredibly well-written, easily installable, highly regarded piece of software. It's free and universally available. It's also the most popular option on Github. Go with connect-redis.

Comment: Convinced me, I'm going for redis! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked all the time in the big-data world and there are a lot of biased opinions about the merits of each.  I recommend using whichever one you are most comfortable with.

With that said, I prefer Mongo with Node because of the ease of conversion from JS objects to MongoDB rows and back.

Comment: Your answer is for a different question.  OP isn't asking about what engine to use to store data in general, this is about where to store expressJS Sessions.  There are various adapters which leverage data stores.  OP mentioned they weren't using MongoDB for other data storage, which means that using connect-mongo might not make sense.