# passport-socketio store property configuration

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I was wondering about how to configure `passport.socketio`.

I read the docs but still can wrap my head on how to set the `store` property.

I'm using `passport-local` .

Here is my code (relevant parts ) :

Some configuration:

```
app.use( express.cookieParser() );
app.use(express.methodOverride());
// use express.session before passport, so that passport session will work
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'somerandomcod3' }));
// Initialize Passport!  Also use passport.session() middleware, to support
// persistent login sessions (recommended).
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**passport.socketio config**

```
  io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser, 
    key:          'express.sid',        
    secret:       'somerandomcod3',  
    store:         express.session,      // not working tried also a couple others
    fail: function(data, accept) { 
      accept(null, false);           
    },
    success: function(data, accept) {

      accept(null, true);
    }
  }));
```

**my local strategy**

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy ;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

  db.userModel.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {

      if (err) {

        return done(err);
      }
      if(isMatch) {

        return done(null, user);
      } else {

        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

So the question is what or better yet how can I get the session store . ?!

Answer (score 1):

The store can be several values. By default the store is MemoryStore, or `express.session.MemoryStore` if you want the exact reference.

MemoryStore is great for no-dependency sessions, but they come with the downside that if your node process is restarted you lose all of your sessions. Basically this is terrible for any production build, so if this is a serious app you should take a look at [this question about different session stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app).

What I believe relevant parts your code should look like is:

```
var express = require("express")
  , app = express()
  , sessionStore = new express.session.MemoryStore(); //or some other kind of store

app.use(express.session({ secret: 'somerandomcod3', store: sessionStore}));

io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    cookieParser: express.cookieParser 
  , key: 'express.sid'   
  , secret: 'somerandomcod3'
  , store: sessionStore
  , fail: function(data, accept) { 
     accept(null, false);           
    }
  , success: function(data, accept) {
     accept(null, true);
   }
}));
```

Hopefully now you have a better understanding :)