# express.session() parsing/altering session at server

Tags: node.js, express, session, extjs, node.js-connect

I want to parse (and alter) all sessions which are stored on the server, if I can do it without using store.

Is there some place where the req.session aggregate is stored? .session is a serverside variable, so it must store all sessions which are active, and should be browsable-alterable.

[session documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

connect's MemoryStore is not designed for production environments. Here are some alternatives: [What is a good session store for a single-host Node.js production app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app)

Here are all storage options: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki#session-stores

You could write a proxy to a service like connect-redis to modify sessions as they're stored or retrieved.