# Memory leak in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, express

I am getting this error

Warning: connection.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.

And not getting exact way to get rid of this problem.

Comment: You're using Express with sessions, and it's telling you that you shouldn't use the built in memory store for production sites, but a database instead. There are modules for Mongo, Redis, MySQL, Cassandra and just about any DB available.

Comment: Lots of other answers to this type of question if you just search for that exact message on Google.  Here's one such answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using MemoryStore in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760620/using-memorystore-in-production)