# Express.js signed cookies between two instances

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

Does anyone know if it's possible to sign and unsign same cookie from different node-express instances?

I have one express instance running which is responsible for user authentication:

1. User logs in
2. User gets signed cookie with credential info

And I have another express/socket.io instance which should consume that signed cookie and use those credentials:

1. After user gets signed cookie connection to socket is made
2. On handshake I want to unsign that cookie
3. User credentials information

Is this possible using express.cookieParser or any other module?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use cookieParser with a shared secret.

(I would generally recommend that you store credential info in a server-based session, rather than encoded in a cookie. Not only is this more secure, but it also allows having multiple instances share the same session info. See [What is a good session store for a single-host Node.js production app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app))

Comment: I tried using cookieParser with same secret on both ends but for some reasons it is not able to unsign it correctly. I think it uses some instance variables to sign the cookie together with secret... Also another idea came to my mind is to use JWT and operate with tokens..

Comment: I cannot find any environment variables being used, only the secret. What version of connect do you have installed? Are you using the the same domain for the cookies and that it is being sent by the browser?