# Storing sessions in express for a business app what should i use?

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I want to create sessions for multiple login for same account now i am storing unique session strings for any particular users now my question is that when i was using express-session then on its documentation page [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) it's mentioned that

**Warning: The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing**

Now my question is that as i am creating an app for business should i use it or not and if i dont use then what will be best for storing sessions i have heard about redis but i have also heard that it consumes much memory that's why can anyone please put some ligt on this i will be really greateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good session store for a single-host Node.js production app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app)

Comment: thanks lucas for suggesting that..

Comment: @LucasCosta i am still unclear as i want good speed retrieval  and also no removing of sessions until my user logs out. can you suggest me what wil be better

Comment: I answered for your tests

Answer (score 1):

The common three more useful options instead `MemoryStore`:

[CookieSession](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/cookieSession.html)

[connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)

[connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app)

I suggest you use `CookieSession`, because is more simple and fast. Simple example from [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session):

```
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))
```

Time for expiry:

> maxAge: a number representing the milliseconds from Date.now() for expiry
>
> expires: a Date object indicating the cookie's expiration date
>   (expires at the end of session by default).

You can set either expires or maxAge on the individual cookie belonging to the current user:

```
// This user should log in again after restarting the browser
req.session.cookie.expires = false;

// This user won't have to log in for a year
req.session.cookie.maxAge = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Comment: will it be good for an business app where 100000 of users are registered on my app ??

Comment: also i do not want to specify time for session as i dont know for how long user will log into my app

Comment: If your doubt is if session supports many users and access, the answer is YES, but the question are more related with structure of servers, programming language (node.js is a great option for many reasons (asyncrouns is one) ), web server (I suggest nginx) and database (nosql is the great option in case of many registers)

Comment: Specify the higher time in `maxAge`

Comment: also as i am using app not website i dont have any use of coookies i am storing the tokens inside variables and passing them as post parametrs  now is there any use of cookies here or not ??

Comment: i dont get your answer i am asking that this cookie-session module related to cookies or not as i dont want to interact with any cookie thing ??

Comment: can i set max age to 1 year or not ??

Comment: i mean can i set a year of time i mean unit will be in milisecs ??

Comment: Also one last question where i am generating the token which i will send to the user using req as params as i told you i am not using cookie because i am designing this for an app ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91880/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-lucas-costa).

Comment: first tell me what are keys here and also in cookie-sessions it is itself creating unique tokens or i have create ??

Comment: does cookie-sessions store sessionsids somewhere in memory or i have to manually store ids ??

Comment: the list of keys to use to sign & verify cookie values. Set cookies are always signed with keys[0], while the other keys are valid for verification, allowing for key rotation.

Comment: session_id stays in memory, if is necessary for verification in the future (audit ex.) can be storage in another place

Comment: now for this storage what should i use redis/mongo or cookie-sessiosn itself handle that ??

Comment: For only local verification in session, can stay in memory. few cases in storage in mongo/redis, but if necessary, can do it

Comment: actually problem i am facing is after restarting the server all sessions is getting deleted can you tell me how to persist the sessions in cookie-sessions ??