# session cache in node js

Tags: node.js, session, caching

I want to do save big data per user which save in the server object and the user can use allowed function which depends on the data in the session. I would like to ask if npm client-sessions can do it for me.
can I save big data?
can it work with mulitple users?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [session middleware for express](https://github.com/expressjs/session) ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)).

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'your-secret', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session
  if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++;
  } else {
    sess.views = 1;
  }
  // ...
})
```

## UPD

> Warning The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
>   purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
>   memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
>   and is meant for debugging and developing.

So there are [many options](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores) for the stores, including [redis store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis).

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```

Comment: I saw in the site : Session data is stored server-side, this is very good. But i also saw the warning : The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process, and is meant for debugging and developing.

Comment: @davidlopez please check the upd

Comment: and what is the difference between express session and client session what is recommended?

Comment: @davidlopez these sessions (express) are stored on the server whilst these (https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) are stored in encrypted cookies. But storing data in cookies ends up in the risk that the user changes them. Since there are some advanced encryption algorithms, it's not likely he'll be able to change the data, but he can *spoil* it. 
I'd rather store session data on the server.

Comment: O.K thanks. I have one more question, I still haven't found the suitable session cache. I want to use express- session but I thing the options for store are not good enough according this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749907/what-is-a-good-session-store-for-a-single-host-node-js-production-app. Cookie session is not good because i want to save the data in the server and the rest are to slow (req/sec)